# Encode string as HTML in Ruby with tags intact

Tags: html, ruby, html-entities

How do I encode strings to HTML but keep the tags intact?

eg

```
<div id='blah'>I am a brown fox > > </div>
```

becomes

```
<div id='blah'>I am a brown fox &gt; &gt; </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an XML/HTML builder like Nokogiri?

Simply install the gem.

`gem install nokogiri`

The following little script I created based on what you provided in your question:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
  doc.div(:id => 'blah') {
     doc.text "I am a brown fox > >"
  }
end

puts builder.to_html
```

Gives the following HTML snippit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<div id="blah">I am a brown fox &gt; &gt;<id>hello</id>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! How do I use this without the header (ie just "<div>...</div>"? I want a string that will be passed to JQuery /eventually/.

Comment: Instead of `puts builder.to_html`, use `puts builder.doc.root.to_s` and that way you don't get the `DOCTYPE`. Please make sure to mark this answered if this solves your problem so that others may see that it's the correct solution you are looking for.